# Can't update and can't install anything due to dependency problem

Tags: command-line, package-management

```
 sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python3-distupgrade
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of python3-distupgrade:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:16.04.21).
 python3-update-manager depends on python3-distupgrade.
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on python3-distupgrade (= 1:16.04.21); however:
  Package python3-distupgrade is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distupgrade (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-distupgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this first, in terminal introduce these commands:

`$ sudo apt-get autoremove
 $ sudo apt-get autoclean
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get -f install`

Now should´t be any dependency problems. Try to install some application.

The other thing you could try is open a terminal with the followng commands:

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
 sudo apt-get update`

Now you should be able to install packages or update.